# Javascript regex pattern match

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to build a regex to meet the following requirement

4 digits / 6 digits / 3 digits

e.g. 4444/666666/333

But, the last slash and 3 digits are optional

Here is what i have so far:

```
/^\d{4}[/]\d{6}[/]{0,1}\d{0,3}$/
```

However, if i enter 4444/666666333 or 4444/666666/ that will also pass :(

Is it possible to put in a condition that will force a slash, if the remaining 3 digits are entered? 
Or, if the final slash is entered, the remaining 3 digits must also be entered too?

thanks
Scott

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this pattern: `^\d{4}\/\d{6}(\/\d{3})?$`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uA3sxk/1)

Comment: Agree. That's it.

Comment: Hi Michal, that works perfect, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

/^\d{4}[/]\d{6}([/]\d{0,3})?$/
use group () to include the last slash and 3 digits ,and use (?) to match it or no

Comment: Hi Peng, that fixes the 4444/666666333 issue, but not 4444/666666/

Comment: Hi Peng, i got it /^\d{4}[/]\d{6}([/]\d{3})?$/ - just removed the range from the last digit, thanks :)